# Check if text exist and remove it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to check if the text exist and remove it. I want to check for example in my code if text **Without Name** exist, if this text exist then I need to remove or hide this elements:

```
<dt>Font</dt>
<dd>no font selected </dd>
<dt>Name</dt>
<dd>--------</dd>
```

And almost the same with the other,  if **With name + date** exist then I need to remove or hide:

```
<dt>Color</dt>
<dd>------- </dd>
```

My HTML is:

```
<table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                <dl class="item-options">
                    <dt>Radio test</dt>
                    <dd>Without Name </dd>
                    <dt>Font</dt>
                    <dd>no font selected </dd>
                    <dt>Name</dt>
                    <dd>--------</dd>
                </dl>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <dl class="item-options">
                    <dt>Radio test</dt>
                    <dd>With name + date </dd>
                    <dt>Font</dt>
                    <dd>Disney Print </dd>
                    <dt>Name</dt>
                    <dd>nametest </dd>
                    <dt>Color</dt>
                    <dd>------- </dd>
                </dl>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 if (jQuery('.item-options dd:contains("Without Name")').length > 0)
 {
 jQuery('.item-options dt:contains("Name")').html('');    
 }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any JS code ?

Comment: You are missing a question here. What code have you tried to do for yourself, what (if any) errors do you see in console, and what about what you have tried does not work?

Comment: I forgot to post it, I add the script is in my post at very bottom, but is not work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not an allowed answer. please give more details...

Comment: thank you for your questions, is solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is syntax error in script tag, as there is unnecessary closing braces are given. So make it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 if (jQuery('.item-options dd:contains("Without Name")').length > 0)
 {
    var parent = $('.item-options dd:contains("Without Name")').parent('dl');
    jQuery(parent).find('dt:contains("Name")').html('');    
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but with this code if I try to remove the Name this will be remove from everywhere, So I need to remove only in the part where is Without name

Comment: @robertD...I have edited answer. try that. it will work.

Comment: Is perfect Dhara Parmar, you save my life, thank you very much